# Dataframe copies based on Boolean variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame:

```
ID <- c("a","a","a","a","d","d","d")
rank <- c(2,3,4,5,1,2,3)
view <- c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
utility <- c(-3,3,-5,3,-6,-3,-15)
temp <- data.frame(ID,rank,view,utility)
```

Within each group (ID), there is a variable (view), which is boolean. For each group, more than one row can have view=1. I need to do the following

1. I need to create copies of each group (all rows of a group) so that the new groups all have just one row with view=1
2. Rename the resulting groups so that the ID continues to be unique (concatenation of ID and rank[view==1] is not mandatory as shown in the example)

This is the output that I need:

```
ID <- c("a2","a2","a2","a2","a4","a4","a4","a4","a5","a5","a5","a5","d1","d1","d1","d3","d3","d3")
rank <- c(2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3)
view <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1)
utility <- c(-3,3,-5,3,-3,3,-5,3,-3,3,-5,3,-6,-3,-15,-6,-3,-15)
temp1 <- data.frame(ID,rank,view,utility)
```

Comment: `c(a,2,1,-3,...)` will produce a `numeric` vector iff `a` is a `numeric` variable. Is there a variable named `a` that we should be using? If not, then ... this produces a syntax error.

Comment: If instead you intend for that to be `c("a",2,1,-3,...)`, and you think that columns 2-4 will be numeric in your resulting frame, then ... that won't work, either, since `c("a",1)` will coerce `1` to `"1"`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Corrected as per r2evans comment. Thanks r2evans

Comment: Is there a reason you want all of your numbers converted to strings? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Thanks again r2evans. I do not want all numbers converted to strings. Re-written code for the dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

temp %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(data = list(select(cur_data(), -view))) %>%
  filter(view == 1) %>%
  unite(ID, ID, rank, remove = FALSE, sep = '') %>%
  select(-utility, rank1 = rank) %>%
  unnest(data)  %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(view = +(rank == rank1)) %>%
  select(-rank1)

#   ID     view  rank utility
#   <chr> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 a2        1     2      -3
# 2 a2        0     3       3
# 3 a2        0     4      -5
# 4 a2        0     5       3
# 5 a4        0     2      -3
# 6 a4        0     3       3
# 7 a4        1     4      -5
# 8 a4        0     5       3
# 9 a5        0     2      -3
#10 a5        0     3       3
#11 a5        0     4      -5
#12 a5        1     5       3
#13 d1        1     1      -6
#14 d1        0     2      -3
#15 d1        0     3     -15
#16 d3        0     1      -6
#17 d3        0     2      -3
#18 d3        1     3     -15
```

`cur_data()` is available in `dplyr` 1.0.0 or higher. For each `ID` we store a list of dataframe that we want to replicate, keep only rows with `view = 1`, combine `ID` and `rank` column to create a new `ID` column and create the new boolean `view` column.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. This worked great and taught me the use of cur_ set of functions.

Answer (score 2):

*data.table* attempt.
The logic is to self-join the `view == 1` cases back against the original set of data, check where the `rank` variables match up, and join the `ID` + `rank` to make the new identifier. I.e.:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(temp)
temp[
  temp[view == 1,],
  on="ID",
  allow.cartesian=TRUE,
  c(.(ID = paste0(ID, i.rank), view = as.integer(i.rank == rank)), .SD ),
  .SDcols = -c("ID","view")
]

#    ID view rank utility
# 1: a2    1    2      -3
# 2: a2    0    3       3
# 3: a2    0    4      -5
# 4: a2    0    5       3
# 5: a4    0    2      -3
# 6: a4    0    3       3
# 7: a4    1    4      -5
# 8: a4    0    5       3
# 9: a5    0    2      -3
#10: a5    0    3       3
#11: a5    0    4      -5
#12: a5    1    5       3
#13: d1    1    1      -6
#14: d1    0    2      -3
#15: d1    0    3     -15
#16: d3    0    1      -6
#17: d3    0    2      -3
#18: d3    1    3     -15
```